# How to pass javascript date to laravel 4 API timestamp

Tags: javascript, laravel

This is the format of my **Javascript** date using `new Date()`

`2015-02-21T13:02:13.175Z`

But the laravel API refuses it. **Laravel** timestamp is like

`2015-02-21 12:55:06`.

What is the best way to match them up, or to format my javascript date like laravel's timestamp. Should I do it in the client or server side?

ps: I can add date today in the server side but I need the javascript date because I'm using offline data that can be synced later. So I need the original date from the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to do in the server side. You should do  `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

So you shall use in the frontend (However it will executed at server)

```
<?php
$DateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//youroperationshere
?>
```

Note : This is the format supported by Laravel by default for `created_at` and `updated_at` columns itself.

Because the

You shall see the format accepted by laravel [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema)

### Update :

As the questioner needs to do the same in front end

```
function generateDateToday(){
    var d = new Date()
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var day = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var hour = ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2);
    var minutes = ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " "+ hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

So your output will be  `2015-02-21 18:1:11` which laravel accepts

Comment: I can't do it purely in the server side because I'm using offline data that can be synced later so I need the original date added in the client side.

Comment: I have updated my answer which will do the same from front end :)

Comment: It's almost working, but I got an error `A two digit minute could not be found`. It only displays `2015-2-21 21:1:43`. But It's ok  I can fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Your formatting is nice and easy to understand, but in the name of performance since it's all a string anyway, I wanted to do it without the extra variables: `var datetime = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
                    ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
                    ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
                    ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
                    ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
                    ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);`